# Parse Tree in StanfordCoreNLP and Stanza giving different result (representation structure)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I did dependency parsing using StanfordCoreNLP  using the code below

```
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05', lang='en')

sentence = 'The clothes in the dressing room are gorgeous. Can I have one?'
tree_str = nlp.parse(sentence)
print(tree_str)
```

And I got the output:

```
  (S
    (NP
      (NP (DT The) (NNS clothes))
      (PP (IN in)
        (NP (DT the) (VBG dressing) (NN room))))
    (VP (VBP are)
      (ADJP (JJ gorgeous)))
    (. .)))
```

How can I get this same output in Stanza??

```
import stanza
from stanza.server import CoreNLPClient
classpath='/stanford-corenlp-full-2020-04-20/*'
client = CoreNLPClient(be_quite=False, classpath=classpath, annotators=['parse'], memory='4G', endpoint='http://localhost:8900')
client.start()
text = 'The clothes in the dressing room are gorgeous. Can I have one?'
ann = client.annotate(text)
sentence = ann.sentence[0]
dependency_parse = sentence.basicDependencies
print(dependency_parse)
```

In stanza It appears I have to split the sentences that makes up the sentence. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Please note that my objective is to extract noun phrases.

Answer (score 3):

There is some documentation on usage here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html#usage

This shows how to get the constituency parse (which is the form of your output example).  The dependency parse is a list of edges between words.

```
# set up the client
with CoreNLPClient(annotators=['tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner', 'parse'], timeout=30000, memory='16G') as client:
    # submit the request to the server
    ann = client.annotate(text)

    # get the first sentence
    sentence = ann.sentence[0]

    # get the constituency parse of the first sentence
    print('---')
    print('constituency parse of first sentence')
    constituency_parse = sentence.parseTree
    print(constituency_parse)

    # get the first subtree of the constituency parse
    print('---')
    print('first subtree of constituency parse')
    print(constituency_parse.child[0])
```

Comment: I have connection issue with `French`